# I have installed 'Image' but, ImportError: No module named Image

Tags: python-2.7

sorry, I cannot English well.
I have installed 'Image' using `pip install Image`
but it give 'ImportError: No module named Image'.

Python version is 2.7.10 (Windows 10)

Comment: Wellcome to SO, sorry but this is probably a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776988/python-2-7-importerror-no-module-named-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Pillow on Windows using pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594800/how-to-install-pillow-on-windows-using-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the way to install it in Windows through pip and the command line is 
`pip install pillow`. I don't know how you import it in your code but this is the way that you should be doing it `from PIL import Image`.

You should also have a look in the documentation of [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/installation.html) for any further questions.